# How to hide Wordpress footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, footer

Ive built a site using a theme in wordpress. One of the modules that I have used in my page is called "Widgetizer" and it allows me to take the information from one of my default widgets (sidebar, upper left footer, footer, upper right footer, etc...) and add it into any place on my site. I setup the information in my upper footer widgets. They are showing exactly as I want them to through the "widgetizer", but they also show in the upper footer area. I have tried to hide the upper footer area completey using:

```
.section .swatch-flylite .section-normal .has-top}
display: none;
}
```

but that clearly isn't working. The site is located at http://flylitechallenge.com/flylite.
Any ideas? If I can hide the Upper Footer section completely, that gives me 3 widgets that can store information so I can place them in other areas of my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this section ..

```
<section class="section swatch-flylite section-normal has-top">
...
</section>
```

.. you are targeting it wrong.
It should be:

```
.section.swatch-flylite.section-normal.has-top {
    display: none;
}
```

(without the spaces and the opening bracket should be the other way around)